# Can CNContactPickerViewController be added as child view controller?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, cncontactviewcontroller

I want to add `CNContactPickerViewController` in a `UITabBarController` as a tab. I've achieved the same thing with `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` but same approach didn't work for `CNContactPickerViewController`. Is there anything I've missed or is it impossible.

Here is what I tried:

Note: When I remove `if #available(iOS 9, *)` it also works in iOS 9.

```
class ContactsViewController: UIViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    var contactsController: UIViewController!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        contactsController = getAddressBook()
        contactsController.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.addChildViewController(contactsController)
        contactsController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.contactsController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(contactsController.view)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getAddressBook() -> UIViewController {
        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
            contactPicker.delegate = self;
            contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]

            return contactPicker
        } else {
            let addressBookController = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
            addressBookController.peoplePickerDelegate = self

            return addressBookController
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this question. Essentially, what you want is pretty similar to the Contacts tab in the native Phone app, right?

Comment: Yes. But I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Did you end up creating your own custom view that imitated it?

Comment: No. I just presented it modally when the tab selected. Ugly solution. `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` works though. You can use it if it suits you

Comment: @Rjdlee Same specification for me and I guess we are not the only ones : having a Contact tab in an application.
Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @CedricSoubrie Sorry, I never found a solution.

Comment: @Rjdlee Me neither :'( 
The only thing to do is either :
a) a big hack to use it in a tab but you'll never get a nice implementation
b) reimplment the exact same view as Apple
c) change the design of you app and display the screen as modal.

In my project I choose the c) solution as I had no time left.